# Pulling data issue

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This formula is applied at `B12`

```
=LET(nn,LET(sortedData,SORTBY(INDIRECT(B1&"!A5:R10998"),
  MATCH(INDIRECT(B1&"!J5:J10998"),Master!C2:C10,0),1,
  MATCH(INDIRECT(B1&"!A5:A10998"),Master!B1:B13,0),1),
  FILTER(sortedData,INDEX(sortedData,0,9)="ABC ROSE","")),IF(nn=0,"",nn))
```

In B1 which is a dropdown it is worksheet name which one can choose and above formula works very fine.

Here,I want to add one condition that if col M12 & below and S12 & below,if it is blank then zero must be exist and rest as above formula does.

All this I require through VBA so the result I can get in value and not in formula.

Below code tried. But I didn't get the result.

```
Sub ApplyFormula()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim formula As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet to "CS"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CS")
    
    ' Check if columns M12 and S12 and below are blank
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("M12:M" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)) = 0 And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("S12:S" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row)) = 0 Then
        
        ' Insert zero in B12
        ws.Range("B12").Value = 0
    Else
        ' Apply the formula in B12
        formula="=LET(nn,LET(sortedData,SORTBY(INDIRECT(B1&""!A5:R10998""),MATCH(INDIRECT(B1&""!J5:J10998""),Master!C2:C10,0),1,MATCH(INDIRECT(B1&""!A5:A10998""),Master!B1:B13,0),1),FILTER(sortedData,INDEX(sortedData,0,9)=""ABC ROSE"","""")),IF(nn=0,"""",nn))"
        ws.Range("B12").Formula = formula
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.Formula2` --> `ws.Range("B12").Formula2 = formula`

Comment: U mean to say, instead of "ws.Range("B12").Formula = formula ",it should be as per your suggestion would be "ws.Range("B12").Formula2 = formula"

Comment: yes - as you are using new array formulas

Comment: I tried using as said by u but I am not getting in values instead it is showing the result as normally when formula used in B12.

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: Here,I want to add one condition that if col M12 & below and S12 & below,if it is blank then zero must be there.But above code doesn't give the result.What is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Formula2` as the formula contains new array formulas.

To retrieve the values use this code:

```vb
With ws.Range("B12")
   .Formula2 = formula
   .SpillingToRange.value = .SpillingToRange.value
End With
```